# Assigning a new key and value pair in Filter Function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

In my node server I have a filter function that looks like this

```js
let totalHours = 0;
let laborCost = 0;
const employees = await Employees.findOne({
  company
});
const timeCards = await TimeCard.find({
  employee: employees.employees
}).populate("employee")
const filterTime = timeCards.filter(element => {
  let totalHoursByEmployee = 0;
  const times = element.times.filter(time => {
    if (time.job === jobId) {
      let hours = parseFloat(new Date(time.hours) / 3600000)
      totalHours += hours;
      totalHoursByEmployee += hours;
      laborCost += hours * time.hourlyRate;
    }
    return time.job === jobId;
  })
  element.totalHoursByEmployee = totalHoursByEmployee;
  element.times = times;
  return element.times.length !== 0;
})
res.json({
  times: filterTime,
  totalHours,
  laborCost
})
```

When I send back my response the front end my times key is an array but it does not contain the key o totalHoursByEmployee in any indexes of the array. I know that filter doesn't mutate the array but am I missing something. If I console log `filterTime[0].totalHoursByEmployee` right before I send my response then the correct number shows on the back end console but when I get it on the front end that key of totalHoursByEmployee is no where to be found.

Comment: Does the network response for that request include the right data as well?

Comment: _"I know that filter doesn't mutate the array"_  no, but you are mutating each `element` as they pass through your `filter` callback.

Comment: Right which is why I'm expecting the key and value of the element that I mutated to show up but it doesn't

Comment: What does your front-end code look like? How is it trying to access the `totalHoursByEmployee` property?

Comment: Just console logging the entire respones from the server on the front end and everything is coming back from it but in the times key is an array with no key of totalHoursByEmployee in it

Comment: Like @FedericoAlecci said, check the response in your browser's _Network_ console.

Comment: I wonder if that property could somehow be non-enumerable and thus will not be included in a `JSON.stringify()`?  You could check by doing this `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(filterTime[0], "totalHoursByEmployee"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer. It is because I am using Mongoose. So when I ran the query of

`const timeCards = await TimeCard.find({ employee: employees.employees }).populate("employee")`

it was returning a mongoose object and the mongoose object will not let you add keys unless they are defined in the Schema. So to fix it I ran

`const timeCards = await TimeCard.find({ employee: employees.employees }).populate("employee").lean()`

The .lean() returns a JSON object and not a mongoose object so now I can add key value pairs to it.